# Accessing observable list in another class

Tags: java

Let's say I have a class:

```
public class FutureTask extends Task<ObservableList<Future>> {
   @Override protected ObservableList<Future> call() throws Exception
     ObservableList<Future> futureList = FXCollections.ObservableArrayList();
     ....
     /// a bunch of things here to build and manipulate the list
     ....
  return futureList;
```

If I had another class

```
public class {
// What would I enter here to get a variable x so:
x = futureList?
```

I tried doing `ObservableList<Future> x = FutureTask.call()` but I keep getting a static reference error.

FutureTask is only used once in the code, so would I have to declare it `static`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ObservableList<Future> x = new FutureTask().call();
```

Will do the magic.

Comment: Ahh yes of course!

How could I forget the new?

Any way to prevent it from throwing up an `unreported exception` error?